# Android что лучше использовать для 2d графики?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сделать маленький конструктор. Что бы была картинка и на ней ещё несколько маленьких. Что бы можно было убирать маленькие картинки. Что лучше использовать canvas  или ещё что-то? Мне не требуется сложная графика и анимация.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, нативные средства Anroid'a не очень удобны для сложных отрисовок (но это мой опыт работы 2-3 года назад, возможно сейчас стало лучше). Поэтому рекомендую использовать игровые движки; как бонус, они кросс-платформенные. Например, опенсорсный [**libGDX**](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com) – использовал его для Андроид-версии [игры TacticToy](https://aivanf.com/rus/note/tactictoy), впечатления хорошие; там **Java**.

Ещё Вам может приглянуться опенсорсный **Godot** – лично не использовал, но многие хвалят; там C++, но есть поддержка других языков. Ещё существует [**GameMaker: Studio 2**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GameMaker:_Studio) и масса других инструментов, платных или более специализированных на 3Д.

Comment: нельзя не упомянуть Unity. Достаточно большое сообщество. можно быстро найти решение проблем. Но порог входа у него выше, чем у LibGDX